# Executing Raw Sql String in C++ Error

Tags: c++, sql, database, t-sql, sybase

I'm trying to execute a raw sql string using my custom Connection class..

(The Execute method simply executes the given sql statement..)

```
MyConnection.Execute(
    "DECLARE @i int "
    "SET @i = 0 "
    "WHILE (@i < 10000) BEGIN "
    "INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 2, 3) "
    "SET @i = @i + 1");
```

Running this statement gives me a syntax error:

```
Code = 80040e14
Code meaning = I
Source = ASEOLEDB
Description = [42000]
[ASEOLEDB] Incorrect syntax near '1'.
```

As you can see, I'm connecting to Sybase Adaptive Server Enterprise, which accepts T-SQL..

I'm assuming there is something wrong with my sql string,, or with how it's formatted?

Thanks

PS I'm sure there's nothing wrong with my "Execute" method, as a single line delete statement works fine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found this example in the web

there is no END at your code and no ; but the ';', i think, you don't need.

```
DECLARE @MyCounter int;
SET @MyCounter = 0;
WHILE (@MyCounter < 26)
BEGIN;
   INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (@MyCounter, CHAR( ( @MyCounter + ASCII('a') ) ) );
   SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1;
END;
```

BR
Alex